# uinavigationcontroller loses tint on state restoration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I set the tint of my navigation controller in the view did load method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self navigationController];
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

The above sets my nav bar to red without issue.

When a user closes the app and the state of the app is encoded and then reopens the app and the state is decoded, the nav bar shows the default white color.

View did load is being called on state restoration but the nav controller is nil.  I am guessing this is why the default color is coming back.

I have set the restoration id on my nav controller as well as the view controller that is changing the color.

Does anyone know what I can do to keep the red color I set for the nav controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the view being loaded before the view controller is added as a child controller of the navigation controller.

Instead of `viewDidLoad`, implement the code in `didMoveToParentViewController:` like so:

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    [super didMoveToParentViewController:parent];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)parent;
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off setting the tint color for the navigation bar in your app delegate when the app launches / is restored.

If this tint color is unique to when one particular view controller is showing, then use the navigation controller's delegate methods as a place to do the setting.

Either way, that will work consistently.